# How to run a javascript function when ANY page is loaded

Tags: javascript, dom

I am doing some maintenance work to a fairly large existing site written in PHP & JavaScript.  I am trying to set up a "time out" so that the user is automatically logged out after a specified period of time.  I think I have the code that will "expire" the users session, but what I need is a way to run a specific javascript function whenever ANY of the pages in the existing system are loaded.  I'd rather not manually add a call in each page as this would take forever and would require even more testing.

Is there a way to add a javascript function call to the window or some other part of the DOM to get called whenever a page is loaded?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you want the user to get logged out after some time even if he is still crawling your website? Can't you use some cookies or PHP sessions instead? Something like: http://www.adampatterson.ca/blog/2010/09/php-user-login-with-sessions/

Comment: How are your webpages built? Is there a header, menu, or footer that is included in all of the pages? If so can you put the javascript call there?

Comment: I'm confused by the last sentence - the DOM or window changes each page load, so of course the only way to run it on each page is to include the code on each page, one way or the other. Not knowing how your site is architected exactly, it's difficult to offer more precise advice.

Comment: @JMax - I like the idea of using a php session, that might be what I try first. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. BUT, you will have to first include a reference to the javascript file.

Then, you can, for instance, use jQuery to detect that the DOM is loaded and ready to call a function of yours.

On a side note, can I ask you why you need to call a javascript function? There are probably other ways to do that, like a listener on your server that redirects to a logout page when a session expires.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, javascript may not be the best solution for this.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Write the javascript in a .js file, host it on your server, and link to the .js from all the pages.  While this does not apply a global rule, it is the only way I can think of and it won't be a problem for testing as the code will be from one source.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You have to have the javascript function load into every page.  But you just have to write it once and then include like:

`<script src="logout.js"></script>`

and then you'll need to set the timer for the logout

```
<body onload="setLogoutTimer()">
```

But in order for every page to have it you either need to explicitly place it in every page.

Answer (score 0):

That depends to your site script. If you're checking your session data on every request this could be done easily.

Add time data for a session's last move, append it to a js script which controls that If it's time to end the session or not. And take action(js redirect or an ajax request)